# laravel 5.2::NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 Error

Tags: php, laravel

currently i have a problem with my project , i am trying to connect with my home page from welcome page and brings the error --*NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 Error*-- i have no clue of the problem but any liitle help i will appreciate , thank you the following is my code :

**php artisan route:list**

```
+--------+----------+-----------------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | POST     | /                     | welcome       |App\Http\Controllers\pagesController@welcome        | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | /                     | welcome       | Closure| web        |
|       | GET|HEAD | account               | account       |App\Http\Controllers\userController@getAccount      | web        |
|        | POST     | basketball            | basketball    |App\Http\Controllers\pagesController@basketball     | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | basketball            |               |App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@basketball     | web        |
|        | POST     | createpost            | post.create   |App\Http\Controllers\PostController@postCreatePost  | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | cricket               |               |App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@cricket        | web        |
|        | POST     | cricket               | cricket       |App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@cricket        | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | delete-post/{post_id} | post.delete   |App\Http\Controllers\PostController@getDeletePost   | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | football              | football      |App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@football       | web        |
|        | POST     | football              | football      |App\Http\Controllers\pagesController@football       | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | formula1              |               |App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@formula1       | web        |
|        | POST     | formula1              | formula1      |App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@formula1       | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | home                  | home          |App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@home           | web        |
|        | POST     | home                  | home          |App\Http\Controllers\pagesController@home           | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | like                  | like          |App\Http\Controllers\PostController@postLikePost    | web        |
|        | POST     | like                  | like          |App\Http\Controllers\PostController@postLikePost    | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | logout                | logout        |App\Http\Controllers\userController@getLogout       | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | premium               | premium       |App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@premium        | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | rugby                 |               |App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@rugby          | web        |
|        | POST     | rugby                 | rugby         |App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@rugby          | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | signin                |               |App\Http\Controllers\pagesController@signin         | web        |
|        | POST     | signin                | signin        |App\Http\Controllers\userController@postsignin      | web        |
|        | POST     | signup                | signup        |App\Http\Controllers\userController@postsignup      | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | signup                |               |App\Http\Controllers\pagesController@signup         | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | stream                | stream        |App\Http\Controllers\PostController@stream          | web        |
|        | POST     | stream                | stream        |App\Http\Controllers\PostController@stream          | web        |
|        | POST     | updateaccount         | account.save  |App\Http\Controllers\userController@postSaveAccount | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | userimage/{filename}  | account.image |App\Http\Controllers\userController@getuserimage    | web        |
+--------+----------+-----------------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::group(['middlewareGroups' => ['web']], function ()
{

    Route::get('/', function() {
        return view('welcome');
    }) -> name('welcome');

    Route::get('/home', [
        'uses' =>'PagesController@home',
        'as'  => 'home',

    ]);
    route::post('/home',[
        'uses'  => 'pagesController@home',
        'as'   => 'home',

    ]);
}
```

**welcome.blade.php**`

```
<a href="{{Route('home')}}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">CONTINUE </button> 
</a>
```

**pagescontroller.php**

```
public function home(){
    return view ('pages.home');
}
```

Comment: Which route(url) are you actually requesting though?

Comment: am trying to request this route -- http://localhost:10080/sportsrave/public/home

Comment: Unsure if this matter, but you should fix the fact that you are not consistent  in the capitalization of `pagesController`. The `{{ route('home') }}` should also be lowercase.

Comment: thanks , i have tried but stiil getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Your third Route call is not a class Call (in routes.php). You have "route" instead of "Route"

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  Route::post('/homePost',[
    'uses'  => 'pagesController@home',
    'as'   => 'homePost',
]);
```

in your `welcome.blade`

```
<a href="{{Route('homePost')}}">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">CONTINUE </button>
```

finally put in your `controller` this

```
public function homePost(){
return view ('pages.home');
```

}

problem is your duplicate route.

Comment: try put route left middleware

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::group(['middlewareGroups' => ['web']], function ()
{

    Route::get('/', function() {
        return view('welcome');
    }) -> name('welcome');

    Route::get('/home', [
        'uses' =>'PagesController@home',//your controller name should match with controller and method too
        'as'  => 'home',

    ]);

}
```

your controller name is "pagescontroller" but in routes you have used use "PagesController@home". try the above code.

Comment: are you sure that your controller name is matching?. I tried your code It is working for me.But i have not used middleware in my case.Make sure your controller and method name match with in route you made.